# How to validate the feeds import data in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I am using the feeds module to import the contents. Here I can able to import the contents as CSV file. But the import not validating field values.

For Ex:

If the node reference field is imported, the field getting inserted even the node reference value not exist.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to implement `hook_feeds_presave()` to check over each value. I found its $entity parameter to be the most useful when checking the values.

```
myModule_feeds_presave($source, $entity, $item) {
  if (!empty($entity->myField->[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid'])) {
    // Maybe do something with that value
  } else {
    // log an error
    watchdog('myModule', 'Required myField was empty', NULL, WATCHDOG_INFO);
    // don't import this row:
    $entity->feeds_item->skip = TRUE;
  }
}
```